# Problem with Session Variable value in ASP.NET Core Project. Takes the value on second time the page Loads

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, session-variables

I have a project in which I have some Records from database in a table. So it displays 10 out of all in each page.

The User check some rows(with checkBox) and I keep those rows Id's and send them with Ajax in GetCheckedList Method when the user push Next Page Button. This methods makes the values a string and Store them as Session Variable.

The problem is that when Index takes Session Value, after GetCheckedList execution the very first time the value is Null but when User navigates for another time in Next or Previous page the Session Value on index is Correct.

Something I lose here with which method runs first but I cant figure it out and I need some help.

Index

```
public  async Task<IActionResult> Index(...)
{
   int pageSize = 10;
   var users = from a in _context.Users
                           select a;
 
  ...
  
  //Session variable 
  var checkedList = HttpContext.Session.GetString("CheckedSession");
            if (checkedList != null)
            {
                    ViewBag.checkedListVB = checkedList;
                     HttpContext.Session.SetString("CheckedSession1", checkedList);
            }

  return View(await App.PaginatedList<User>.CreateAsync(users.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

GetCheckedList

```
public RedirectResult GetCheckedList(List<string> values, string text)
{  
   List<string> str = values;
   str.RemoveAll(item => item == null);
   List<int> intList = str.ConvertAll(int.Parse);

   var finalCheckList = string.Join(",", intList);


                if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("CheckedSession") != null)
                {
                    var temp = HttpContext.Session.GetString("CheckedSession");
                    string[] tempStringList = temp.Split(",");
                    var removeEmptytemp = tempStringList.Where(o => o != "").ToArray();
                    int[] myIntsTemp = Array.ConvertAll(removeEmptytemp, int.Parse);
                    List<int> myIntsTempList = myIntsTemp.ToList();

                    List<int> ulist = myIntsTempList.Union(intList).ToList();

                    var now = string.Join(",", ulist);
                    finalCheckList = string.Join(",",now);
                }

   HttpContext.Session.SetString("CheckedSession", finalCheckList);

   return new RedirectResult(url: "/Users/Index", permanent: false,
                             preserveMethod: true);
}
```

Comment: Based on the code above, you're never setting the session variable.  Your Index method is only using SetString if checkList DOES NOT EQUAL null and nothing in GetCheckedList is using SetString.  So, as far as I can tell, you're never setting the value.  Also Index method refers to "CheckedSession1" but everything else is just using "CheckedSession" (without the '1').

Comment: You are right, in my effort to keep unnecessary details out , I pasted wrong text. I edit the code now.

Comment: What about that discrepancy between "CheckedSession" and "CheckedSession1"?

Comment: I keep it for another function , and was one of the ways I could get it. I think it isn't part of my problem. I think the problem is that when Next is pressed, First Index is executing so value will be Null , then GetCheckedList sets the Session Variable right , and only when user hits Next or Prev the Index (which runs first again) will have the sessions value right